# How to add specific keys of a dict to another dict if a condition is met?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, if-statement, key

So, I have a problem where I have to take specific keys and their corresponding values and add them to a new dict if and only if a condition is met. More specifically, I define a function `pokemon_by_types(db, types)` where it checks if the type of a Pokemon in the given database matches with a type in a *list* of strings.

The format of the given database is as such:

```
sample_db = {
"Bulbasaur": (1, "Grass", "Poison", 45, 49, 49, 45, 1, False),
"Charmander": (4, "Fire", None, 39, 52, 43, 65, 1, False),
"Charizard": (6, "Fire", "Flying", 78, 84, 78,100, 1, False),
"Moltres": (146, "Fire", "Flying", 90,100, 90, 90, 1, True),
"Crobat": (169, "Poison", "Flying", 85, 90, 80,130, 2, False),
"Tornadus, (Incarnate Form)": (641, "Flying", None, 79,115, 70,111, 5, True),
"Reshiram": (643, "Dragon", "Fire", 100,120,100, 90, 5, True)
}
```

As you can see, index 1 and 2 will always be the location for type.

I need to make a function that checks a given dict in the above format and sees if the types (either one, at least one is needed for an if statement to be true) match with the given list of strings "types".

If they do indeed match, I need to add those specific keys and values to an empty dict.

Below is the code I have so far:

```
def pokemon_by_types(db, types):
    tdb={}
    for pokemon in db:
        if ((db[pokemon])[1]) or ((db[pokemon])[2]) in types:
            tdb.update(db)
    return tdb
```

Currently, nothin is being added to the dict 'tdb'.

Comment: your condition is not doing what you think it is doing, you mean `if db[pokemon][1] in types or db[pokemon][2] in types:` Also, you don't want to update with `db`, because that will update the *entire dictionary. You could just do `tbd[pokemon] = db[pokemon]`

Comment: How are you calling your method?

Comment: @Robert Seaman I'm calling function using a separate tester file. Juanpa.arrivillaga: thanks that makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dict comprehension to get the items you're looking for:

```
def pokemon_by_types(db, types):
    return {pokemon: info for pokemon, info in db.items() if (info[1] in types or info[2] in types)}
```

A problem with your example is: `if ((db[pokemon])[1]) or ((db[pokemon])[2]) in types:`

This is saying, if `((db[pokemon])[1])` returns `True` OR if `((db[pokemon])[2])` is in `types`.

You have to specify each condition: `if db[pokemon][1] in types or db[pokemon][2] in types:`

Another problem is `tdb.update(db)`. This will actually add all of the elements into tdb if the `if` statement evaluated to `True`.

Comment: You should really take the time to explain *why the OPs approach was wrong* instead of dumping a one-liner on them.